# Как сделать обратный transition цвета в CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Недавно начал верстку сайта. Я задал transition почти каждому элементу на сайте - работает все красиво и слажено. Так вот сейчас стоит задача: сделать обратный transition, то есть задержку при отведении курсора. Подскажите как это можно реализовать, и какой вообще для этого существует псевдокласс в CSS?

Comment: на css не предусмотрено такого события, js mouseLeave/Out в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавляете свойство `transition` не только на `hover`

```css
span {
  transition: color .5s;
}

span:hover {
  transition: color .5s;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Text</span>
```

Comment: достаточно задать transition только для самого элемента

Comment: Большое спасибо, не знал о существовании дополнения "color" к свойству transition. Все работает прекрасно.

Answer (score 0):

`transition-delay` для задержки. `ease-in-out` для обратной анимации

```css
button {

  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #63AEEE;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

button:hover {

  background: #FF6040;
}
```

```html
<button>qeqqe</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :)